# Setting/Resetting the value of a variable that is declared and initialized in __init__ in __main__

Tags: python, nameerror

I would like to set/ reset the value of a variable that I initialized in **init** in the **main**.  I have the following code.

```
class myClass:

    def myfun(self):

       # code using the url

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = None

if __name__ == '__main__':

   # list of integers
   my_list = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
   count = 0

   for item in my_list:
       if count % 2 == 0:
           self.url = "http://myurl.com" # I want to set/reset my url here
```

I received this error:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

What can I do to set/reset my variable that can be used globally later on in all the methods of my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your class, and use this name to refer to your class, not `self`. Like this:

```
class myClass:

    def myfun(self):
        pass
       # code using the url

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = None

if __name__ == '__main__':

   # list of integers
   my_list = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
   count = 0
   obj = myClass() # HERE!
   for item in my_list:
       if count % 2 == 0:
           obj.url = "http://myurl.com"
```

You need to refer to your class as `obj` after instantiating it (or any other name you gave it). If you don't instantiate a class, it's just some kind of skeleton with pre-defined properties and behaviors, but that doesn't exist yet. You can't manipulate it before instantiation.

After it's instantiated, you can refer to it with the instance name, `obj` in my example. `self` in a class refers to itself, no matter what it's called when instantiated. So outside of the class, you can't use `self`.

Comment: `cls` is conventionally used for class objects. `obj` or `inst` would be less misleading, since the instance is not a class.

Answer (score 1):

The import guard `if __name__ == '__main__':` and everything in it is in the global namespace. It's not part of your class, much less a method in the class. To have an instance of your class, you need to instantiate it:

```
my_obj = myClass()
```

Now, in the same namespace, you can do

```
my_obj.url = ...
```

followed by

```
my_obj.myfun()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a class variable.

> that can be used globally later on in all the methods of my class

When you use `self.url`, if there is no `url` attribute in instance, it will refer class variable. It is shared by all instances. If you define `self.url` on some instances, their `self.url` will be shadowed.

```py
class MyClass:
    url = None

    def my_fun(self):
        print(self.url)
        # code using the url


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # list of integers
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    count = 0
    my_object = MyClass()

    for item in my_list:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            MyClass.url = "http://myurl.com"  # I want to set/reset my url here
            my_object.my_fun()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is self represents the object created from the class, and is not accessible in the `if main` statement.

`self` should only be used inside the class methods.

You would need to instantiate myClass then call myClass.url

for example:

```
class MyClass:

def myfun(self):

   # code using the url

def __init__(self):
    self.url = None

if __name__ == '__main__':

   # list of integers
   my_list = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
   count = 0
   my_class = MyClass()


   for item in my_list:
       if count % 2 == 0:
           my_class.url = "http://myurl.com" # I want to set/reset my url here
```

I also took the liberty of renaming your class to MyClass as this is more pythonic